# How to get a specific value in an Object in React Native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native, jsx

I'm currently coding my first app using React Native and using iTunes' search API.

I put a TextInput and a Button which returns all the albums corresponding to the text. Once you click an album, it takes its unique ID and searches the details of this album.

```
export function getAlbumDetailFromApi(id)
{
  return fetch('https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id='+id)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

Here is the class:

```
class AlbumDetail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      album: undefined,
      isLoading: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.idAlbum)
    getAlbumDetailFromApi(this.props.navigation.state.params.idAlbum).then(data => {
      this.setState({
        album: data,
        isLoading: false
      })
    })
  }

  _displayLoading() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.loading_container}>
          <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  _displayFilm() {
    const { album } = this.state

    console.log(album.results.artistId)
    console.log()
    if (album != undefined) {
      return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollview_container}>
          <Text style={styles.title_text}>name of the album should go here</Text>     
        </ScrollView>
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
        {this._displayLoading()}
        {this._displayFilm()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

If my album ID is '1474669063', the function will return that:

[API's response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmfa9.png)

But here is my problem. Maybe it's super simple but I've tried everything I found but I can't access the data...

Could someone help me please?

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: @GauravRoy it says 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'album.results')

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" to the title. When an answer is accepted, it automatically marks the question as solved, so there is no need to have that in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fetching:**

```
  getAlbumDetailFromApi(id) {
    return fetch('https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id='+id)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        // set the state here, we access the first object of the results array with data.results[0}
        this.setState({album: data.results[0]})
        })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
```

**Render Method:**

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getAlbumDetailFromApi(1474669063);
  }
  renderAlbum() {
    // if we have an album display it 
    if (this.state.album) {
      return (
        <View>
        <Text> Arist: {this.state.album.artistName}</Text>
        <Text> Release Date: {this.state.album.releaseDate}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    
  }
  render() {
    console.log('state', this.state);
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderAlbum()}
    </View>
  );
  }
```

**Demo**

https://snack.expo.io/aKlDZLLbF

Comment: @nicvlas You're welcome. Please accept my answer (by clicking the check icon beside my answer) and upvote it (by pressing "^" next to my answer). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in function `getAlbumDetailFromApi`.

It does not return the response. It's returning `promise`.

Considering your code, you should use `async/await` and return the response only. So, your `setState` have data part.

```
export async function getAlbumDetailFromApi(id) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=' + id);
    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But now, do you know how I can access the data in "results"? I always get 'undefined is not an object' Thank you :)